# Salesforce Communtiy

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-community, community, site.com

This is actually a generic question. I am trying to understand the differences between Customer/Partner Community and Force.com Sites and Site.com. I understand the difference between Force.com Sites and Site.com. However I am not being able to understand the link between them and the Customer/Partner Community. I have very little idea regarding this and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As name suggests, Community is used to allow external users to collaborate with internal Salesforce users.

You can use Customer or Partner Community based on the access.

Users have very limited access with Customer Community. If your users need a little more access and need to have sharing rules, Account teams functionality,etc. you can use Partner Community.

You can create Community with two of the following options​:

1. Site.com:

   - Choose existing templates which can be customized upto an extent using Site.com
2. Force.com Sites:

   - Use custom pages with Force.com sites. This can bit customized as you want but needs lots of development experience.

Refer this link for more details-

- [What’s the Difference Between Community Builder (Site.com) and Force.com Sites?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_vs_sites.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: + Salesforce Customer/Partner Community is built on top of Force.com Site and Site.com.